# Why would a .woff font not render on server

Tags: webfonts

My MVC4 website uses a .woff font, which is stored locally within my Visual Studio project (RootFolder/Content/font/myfont.woff).

When I debug locally, it works fine (meaning, I can see the desired font).

I then publish to the remote server, test it and the font isn't doing what it should be doing. I can see the relevant text, but with the 'default' font

I logged onto my remote server, and have verified the files are there!

I know the font I'm using is not installed on the server, but that I don't think matters from what I've read.

My CSS is simply

```
@font-face {
    font-family: corsive;
    src: url("font/MT.woff") format('woff');
}

h1,h3 {
    font-family: 'corsive';
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

If I visit `mysite.com/content/font/MT.woff` then the browser tries to open it.

My site doesn't use SSL, so it's HTTP only.

The same issue persists in FireFox, Chrome and IE

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the file from outside directly?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, you mean as a file... Yes, when I access the page, the browser tries to download it

Comment: @MrLister , good idea, updated

Comment: More questions. 1) which browser, and have you tried others? 2) http or https? 3) would it be too much to ask what the URI of the server is?

Comment: By the way, .tiff is not a font format, so I assume that's not what you meant. You meant .ttf right?

Comment: if you mean the web url i'm testing, of course: www.body-nurture.co.uk @MrLister --- at the top, you see an email and a phone number, that entire "row" should have a slight "italicy" slanted font

Comment: My browser says http://www.body-nurture.co.uk/font/MTCORSVA.woff does not exist. Is that how the font is spelled (all in upper case)?

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault, I've been trying random things... I'm republishing, in 5 minutes  you'll see the "correct" (meaning, it works in debug)code @MrLister

Comment: Is `http://www.body-nurture.co.uk/css` a subdirectory?

Comment: @MrLister, No... I have a folder called Content.In that my css files and a folder called font! Ahhh, I see what you're getting at... I wonder if the Bundle which has done that minifiying stuff has created a virtual folder or similar... Right, time to republish...

Comment: @MrLister, if you understood my last comment, feel free to make it your answer so I can give you some points to say thanks as it was this

Comment: I'm not sure which of my comments was the answer now... From the outside here I can't see what folders you have and which ones are virtual...

Comment: @MrLister, when you use the bundle for CSS in MVC, it minifies the lot. My guess is, when it does this, as you spotted (which made me try what I did), it created this thing called css (view source and you'll note  `<link href="/Css?v=9w2......" rel="stylesheet"/>`). My guess is, the css is now referencing other sub folders from this new virtual folder. So, I updated my CSS to `src: url("../Content/font/MT.woff") format('woff');`

Comment: OK, but you really found this out yourself. All I could see from the source was that the url for the woff was not what you said it should be. You should answer your own question, with the explanation of what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

IIS has security settings that by default deny access to any file extension that has not been defined in MIME types. As the direct link to the font file doesn't seem to work, but causes a 404, this might be the case.

Normally a .woff file extension has no MIME type set, so check the server configuration.